threeJS and overlay in safari
I have a website that uses threeJS. It is rendering to a canvas and it has a white clear color (renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)).
I also have a div that gets rendered on top of it as an overlay for a drawer.
This overlay is animated onto the screen.
The problem is that when this runs on safari, the overlay gets rendered in a weird fashion

notice how the overlay effect is rendered differently for the canvas that threeJS is connected to in comparison with the canvas below it that I am copying the result into.
I would assume that this has something to do with how safari handles webGL connections, but is there any way around it?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.168.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #overlay {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                pointer-events: none;
                opacity: 0;
                animation: fadein 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
            }
            @keyframes fadein {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                100% {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
        <canvas id="static"></canvas>
        <button id="button">test</button>
        <script>
            document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(document.querySelector("#overlay")) {
                    document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector("#overlay"))
                    return;
                }
                const div = document.createElement("div");
                div.id = "overlay";
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            })
        </script>
        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'three';

            let camera, scene, renderer;
            let mesh;

            init();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
                camera.position.z = 2;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();


                const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
                const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( 300, 300 );
                animate()
                //renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
                document.querySelector("#container").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            }

            function animate() {

                mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                document.querySelector("#static").getContext("2d").drawImage(renderer.domElement,0,0)

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




Would you mind to elaborate what you mean by saying "... the overlay effect is rendered differently for the canvas that threeJS is connected to in comparison with the canvas below it ... "? There's only one overlay element that is placed above both <canvas> elements (the one placed into <div id="container"> via Three's renderer.domElement and the <canvas id="static"> one). Your picture does not show any differnce in regards to these elements. If you refer to the "growing" animation it performs, this is due to the removal/insertion of the whole element that you do on click.

Additionally it seems that your stack snippet does not work correctly, because the second <canvas> is not visible or nothing is rendered into it.

yes, the overlay is rendered on top of both elements. But there is a sort of "growing" effect from the top left corner where the canvas is, and that is not because of the css animation that just sets opacity on the whole overlay that covers the screen. If everything was working flawlessly then I shouldn't be able to see the boundary of my canvas as shown by the gif in my question. Regarding the second canvas, it does show up with a pink square for me

The "growing" effect is due to multiple reasons. The main reason you see it is because you insert and remove the overlay element when the button is clicked, so the browser adds the element, then simultaneously paints it and applies the animation to it.
It seems there's no need to completely remove/reinsert the element, so the below solution avoids that step and only toggles the opacity. In my code I additionally replaced the animation with a simpler transition, because the animation only toggled between 2 opacity states (0/1) and with a transition you don't have to worry about iteration counts, starting/stopping the animation, etc.
List of changes:

Replaced the animation with a transition
Added permanent <div id="overlay"></div> element
Changed click handler body



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.168.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #overlay {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                pointer-events: none;
                opacity: 0;
                /* REPLACED THE ANIMATION WITH A TRANSITION */
                transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
                /* REPLACED THE ANIMATION WITH A TRANSITION */
            }
        </style>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
        <canvas id="static"></canvas>
        <button id="button">test</button>
        <!-- NEW OVERLAY ELEMENT -->
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <!-- NEW OVERLAY ELEMENT -->
        <script>
            // CHANGED SCRIPT
            const overlayEl = document.querySelector('#overlay');
            document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                const opacity = Number(overlayEl.style.opacity);
                overlayEl.style.opacity = opacity === 1 ? 0 : 1;
            })
            // CHANGED SCRIPT
        </script>
        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'three';

            let camera, scene, renderer;
            let mesh;

            init();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
                camera.position.z = 2;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();


                const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
                const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( 300, 300 );
                animate()
                //renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
                document.querySelector("#container").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            }

            function animate() {

                mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                document.querySelector("#static").getContext("2d").drawImage(renderer.domElement,0,0)

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




Looking at the example in Chrome 128.0.6613.120 on MacOS, I cannot see anything being painted onto the second canvas. Just mentioning, because that's not the problem that was asked about.

